# Обновление строки базы данный через 24 часа

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть сайт, база данный которого `MySql` а backend `php`. В таблице - `tb_posts`, у каждой строки есть столбцы: текста, даты и приоритета.

Например:

```
tb_posts

id  | text   |      date      | priority
----------------------------------------
 1  |  dfgd  |  03.06.2019    | 10
```

мне нужно чтобы по истечении 24 часов, приоритет поста уменьшился на 1 пункт, то есть стал 9.

**Как мне это организовать?**. С помощью `php` скрипта, который будет каждое определенное время проверять истечение 24 часов? А если будет 1000000000 записей? Тогда сервер просто не справиться с таким количеством данных за одну секунду, а мне нужно чтобы приоритет обновился сразу (через 24 часа) и с несильной нагрузкой на сервер.

Буду рад любому ответу. Спасибо.

Comment: *Как мне это организовать?* Использовать [Event Sheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). PHP в этом процессе вообще не участвует. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+event+scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если Вы хотите чтобы это обрабатывал сам mysql сервер - то по поводу этого есть прекрасная техническая документация: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual - Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)

С правой стороны есть селектор в котором Вы можете, выбрать нужную Вам версию MySQL.

2. Если всё таки хотите чтобы это обрабатывалось на PHP, то порекомендую Вам копнуть в сторону очереди задач: [Supervisor: A Process Control System](http://supervisord.org/)
   Но к нему придётся написать, обработчик.